# returning a string from the string array lengths equal to the input integer

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops, if-statement

I'm trying to make a method that will return a String by having a sentence built from the `eleloosp` array up to `j` elements. So if `j = 3` then the output would be `" How about a nice "`.
I don't want to hardcode the if statements by doing something like `if(j == 3)` then output this specific thing.

How would I do this so I can take the input integer and not hardcode the if statements.

```java
public class TestForEachLoop
{
    private String[] eleloosp = {"How", "about", "a", "nice","tea"};

    public String getCF(int j){
        for(int i = 0; i < eleloosp.length; i++){
            if( j == eleloosp.length){
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would a value of 3 give a returned string with *four* elements in? Have you tried using `StringJoiner`? And what does this have to do with the array length? I'm afraid your question is quite unclear at the moment.

Comment: What im trying to do is make a method that returns a string that will have a sentence composed from the eleloosp array up to j elements. I know I have to use if statements but how do I take the inputed number from j and make that equal to eleloosp array without hardcoding the numbers in the if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this with the following code:

```
public class Main {
    static String[] eleloosp = { "How", "about", "a", "nice", "tea" };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getCF(2));
        System.out.println(getCF(3));
    }

    public static String getCF(int j) {
        String sentence = "";
        assert(j < eleloosp.length);

        for(int i = 0; i < j; i++){
           sentence += eleloosp[i] + " ";
        }

        return sentence;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
How about
How about a
```

Let me know if you're helped with this!

Answer (score 1):

There can be many ways to do it. A concise way to do it by using the following functions:

1. [`String#join`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#join(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence...))
2. [`Arrays#copyOfRange`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(T%5B%5D,%20int,%20int))
3. [`Integer#min`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#min(int,int))

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    static String[] eleloosp = { "How", "about", "a", "nice", "tea" };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(getCF(3));
        System.out.println(getCF(2));
        System.out.println(getCF(8));
    }

    public static String getCF(int j) {
        return String.join(" ", Arrays.copyOfRange(eleloosp, 0, Integer.min(j + 1, eleloosp.length)));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
How about a nice
How about a
How about a nice tea
```